# This problem is about Summation of two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I care about the results of $\large\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^4} + {a^4}}}}$ and $\large \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{n^2}}}{{{n^4} + {a^4}}}} , (a\geqslant0)$ ,can you give me a help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your care,I just made changes of my question,and wish you can have a look .

Comment: You could be interested in the fact that nobody has yet found a closed form for the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}$$ (called Apery's constant). In other words, you can't always solve such series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Write first
$$\frac 1 {n^4+a^4}=\frac{1}{\left(n^2-i a^2\right) \left(n^2+i a^2\right)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 1 {n^4+a^4}=\frac i {2a^2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2+i a^2}-\frac{1}{n^2-i a^2} \right)$$ and remember the famous
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1 {n^2+k}=\frac{\pi  \sqrt{k} \coth \left(\pi  \sqrt{k}\right)-1}{2 k}$$

Same approach for the second one.